# Buttons are not working

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6

Hello I am following [this](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/developing-ios8-apps-using-swift-create-a-to-do-application/) tutorial with a little bit of enhancements of my own. 
Unfortunately I am stuck at one point where I can't find out what to do.. (I am doing all of this for training/learning purposes so im pretty new to iOS development).

At the step where I have to **Add a Segue to Navigate Back** I did whatever the tutorial said but it won't bring me back to the original view once I am at the ViewController and press Cancel or Done.

[image: Image of the app]

I did add a new header file called GroceryListTableViewController.h containing

```
@interface GroceryListTableViewController (Workaround)

-(IBAction)unwindToList: (UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;

@end
```

And I have changed the classname of the GroceryListTableViewController.swift to

```
@objc(GroceryListTableViewController)class GroceryListTableViewController: UITableViewController
```

Then as last step I pointed both buttons to the Exit element above the ViewController.

Somehow everything works except those 2 buttons. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The woraround with a separate .h file is for early beta versions of Xcode and no longer necessary. You can delete the .h file.

In the class file where your segue should go to, put the code you want to perform, such as:

```
@IBAction func cancel(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!) {
    // code here
}

@IBAction func done(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!) {
    // code here
}
```

Then, in your storyboard ctrl-drag from the navigation button to the Exit icon:

[image]

When you release the mouse button, the 2 functions appear. Choose the appropriate action for that button:

[image]

That's it. Hope that helps.